# Updating fields with default values depending of the finded string

Tags: ms-access, select, syntax, sql-update, subquery

libelle_operation field in table tblOperation is imported from an incomplete external file. This field contains in some cases a string ("PADDOCK" in this example) corresponding to a tblTiers.id_tiers.

Other fields in table tblOperation (id_tiers, id_type_operation and id_categorie_budget) are null and should be update with the default values (libelle_tiers, id_type_operation and id_categorie_budget).
Table tblTiers contains the default values for the most recurrent  id_tiers ("PADDOCK" is one of them).

The structure of the database is : [image: database structure]

Dataset for table tblTiers is:

[image: data for tbale tblTiers]

Table tblOperation contains initially :

[image: table tblOperation inital dataset]

And should contain this after "PADDOCK" has be found in libelle_operation and id_tiers, libelle_tiers and id_categorie_budget set to default value accordingly to default values stored in table tablTiers.

[image]

What should be the correct SQL statment for achieving this result?

Comment: Why would you need same value in two fields in tblOperation? Why are tblTiers and tblCompte linked to both tblPrevision and tblOperation? Why would you need to replicate data in multiple tables? Retrieve related data in SELECT queries that join tables, don't duplicate.

Comment: An explanation is now in the edited question.

Comment: That SQL makes no sense. UPDATE needs a SET clause and = to a nested query is meaningless. If id_tiers is null then how do you expect to join tables? Was that an error in your question?

Comment: Edit question to show raw data and desired result in text tables.

Comment: This is done in edited question

Comment: For future, note that data should be provided as text tables, not images. Images can be hard to read and often must be opened in separate window and even then sometimes hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears a partial link is possible with id_compte. Use WHERE clause to provide additional criteria to associate records.

```
UPDATE tblOperation INNER JOIN tblTiers ON tblOperation.id_compte = tblTiers.id_compte
SET tblOperation.id_tiers = tblTiers.id_tiers, tblOperation.id_type_operation = tblTiers.id_type_operation, tblOperation.id_categorie_budget = tblTiers.id_categorie_budget
WHERE libelle_operation LIKE "*" & libelle_tiers & "*";
```